# Add a custom string to list of strings while scraping data from a table

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the data from a table using:

```
url = 'https://www.medicineindia.org/brands-for-generic/512/abacavir'
url_id = '512'
page_source = req.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source.text,"html5lib")

res = []
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table table-striped table-bordered'})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()]
    print(row)
    if row:
        res.append(row)
```

I'm getting output like this:

```
['ABAVIR', 'Genix Pharma', 'TAB', '300 mg', '₹\xa06500.00']
['ZIAGEN', 'Glaxo Smithkline', 'Tablet', '300 mg', '₹\xa00.00']
['ABAMUNE', 'Cipla Limited', 'Tablet', '300 mg', '₹\xa01444.50']
['VIROL', 'Ranbaxy Laboratories Limited', 'Tablet', '300 mg', '₹\xa02350.00']
```

What I want is to add the url_id string to each list e.g. like this:

```
['512', 'ABAVIR', 'Genix Pharma', 'TAB', '300 mg', '₹\xa06500.00']
['512', 'ZIAGEN', 'Glaxo Smithkline', 'Tablet', '300 mg', '₹\xa00.00']
['512', 'ABAMUNE', 'Cipla Limited', 'Tablet', '300 mg', '₹\xa01444.50']
['512', 'VIROL', 'Ranbaxy Laboratories Limited', 'Tablet', '300 mg', '₹\xa02350.00']
```

I tried doing like this:

```
 row = [url_id + tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()]
```

output im getting is:

```
['512ABAVIR', '512Genix Pharma', '512TAB', '512300 mg', '512₹\xa06500.00']
['512ZIAGEN', '512Glaxo Smithkline', '512Tablet', '512300 mg', '512₹\xa00.00']
['512ABAMUNE', '512Cipla Limited', '512Tablet', '512300 mg', '512₹\xa01444.50']
['512VIROL', '512Ranbaxy Laboratories Limited', '512Tablet', '512300 mg', '512₹\xa02350.00']
```

Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

Init the array with index already in place and update with TR data

```py
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [url_id]
    row.extend([tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()])
```

Another option is to insert the ID after creating the array

```py
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()]
    row[0:0] = [url_id]
    #or
    row.insert(0, url_id)
```

Comment: row.insert(0, url_id)...solved the problem, thanks for the help....